# API to search cities by name and zip code in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a small application in vb.net which include one textbox, one search button and one label.

I searched all over the internet but i didn't find what i was looking for so i hope you will give me a hand of help.

My application have a simple role, to detect cities by name or zip code ( the textbox component should behave like a search box for cities, villages and so on.. ). then by clicking the button label take the text of the textbox.

I know that I can do the last part with this small line of code : label.text = textbox.text.

But I dont know where to find a good map API and a good function for the textbox to behave like a searchbox.

I searched into stackoverflow topics but nothing helped me. Maybe somebody else will need this too in the furure...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi adrian, welcome to SO. Your question is too broad. Please have a look into this to improve your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Its off topic because it is asking for an off site resources

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've used the [GeoCoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1):

Which can be called like this:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=94016&sensor=true`

which returns this JSON data:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "94016",
               "short_name" : "94016",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Outer Mission",
               "short_name" : "Outer Mission",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Daly City",
               "short_name" : "Daly City",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "San Francisco County",
               "short_name" : "San Francisco County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Daly City, CA 94016, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.71,
               "lng" : -122.45
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.7113489802915,
                  "lng" : -122.4486510197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.7086510197085,
                  "lng" : -122.4513489802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJWSqQqDx8j4ARXJte4A-IYow",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

As for textboxes working like search boxes, that is a very broad subject! Try some tutorials from W3Schools like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) about forms, and get back to us with any questions.

Hope this helps!